# discord is not defined discord.js 13 problem with ban.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I know this is basic error but someone can help me with it? I'm too dumb for it...

I would like to make ban command but something wrong with the code, I code for like 2 weeks so please be understanding, Thank you.

This is my main file

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES" , "GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS" , "DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS" , "GUILD_MEMBERS"] , partials: ["MESSAGE" , "CHANNEL" , "REACTION"]  });

const prefix = '-';
const welcome = require('./commands/welcome'); // Add This

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of  commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);  
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('BOT is online!');
    setInterval(() => {
        const statuses = [
            `-HELLO`,
            `TEST2 `,
        ]

        const status = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random() * statuses.length)]
        client.user.setActivity(status, { type: "WATCHING"}) // Can Be WATCHING, STREAMING, LISTENING
    }, 2000) // Second You Want to Change Status, This Cahnges Every 2 Seconds
    
    welcome(client)
});

client.on('messageCreate' , message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'TEST') {
        client.commands.get('TEST').execute(message, args, Discord);
    } else if (command === 'rr') {
        client.commands.get('rr').execute(message, args, Discord, client); 
    } else if (command === 'ban') {
        client.commands.get('ban').execute(message, args, Discord, client, Discord.CommandInteraction);
    }
});

client.login('my token')
```

This is my ban file

```
const {Client, CommandInteraction, MessageEmbed} = require(discord.js);

module.exports = {
    name: "ban",
    description: "BAN",
    permission: "ADMIN",
    options: [
        {
            name: "target",
            description: "b",
            type: "user",
            required: true,
        },
        {
            name: "reason",
            description: "b",
            type: "STRING",
            required: true,
        },
        {
            name: "messages",
            description: "t",
            type: "STRING",
            required: true,
                
            choises: [
                {
                    name: "7 days",
                    value: "7",
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
    /**
     * 
     * @param {Client} client 
     * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction 
    */
    execute(client, interaction) {
        const Target =interaction.options.getMember('target');
        const Amount = interaction.options.getString('messages')

        Target.ban({ days: Amount, reason: reason })

        interaction.followUp({ embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("GREEN").setDescription(` **$${Target.user.username}**bye`)] })
    }
}
```

Here error:

```
const { Client, CommandInteraction, MessageEmbed } = require(discord.js);
                                                           ^
ReferenceError: discord is not defined
```

I would be grateful if someone wrote me what I did wrong and also told me what I should add / remove / replace. I'm too beginner to get answers like "Forgot to add ... so add it"
Please let me know what exactly should I add and where, thank you for  your patient and help!

Comment: Missing quotes: `require(discord.js);` should be `require('discord.js');`

Comment: Is there anything else wrong? (I changed the prefix to "/") On the YouTube tutorial that I watched, after typing "/", the bot's avatar is displayed, but it does not show up for me, what's wrong?

Comment: I think those are slash commands: https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#registering-slash-commands

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is interpreting `discord` as an object in the require statement as you have not already defined it as a string, it must be a string to be properly required and imported.

change

```js
const { Client, CommandInteraction, MessageEmbed } = require(discord.js);
```

to

```
const { Client, CommandInteraction, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
```